# Questions about :first-of-type:before:hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I am playing around with someone's codepen and wanted to add some arrows from fontawesome to the code.

I was able to add the arrow with the following code:

```
.button:first-of-type:before {
 content: "\f100";
 font-family: fontAwesome;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1em;
 z-index: 10;
 margin: 20px 0 0 -75px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

This works, but when someone hovers the button, I want the before css to be display none.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
.button:before:hover:first-of-type {
 display: none;
}
```

and

```
.button:first-of-type:before:hover {
display: none;
}
```

and

```
.button:first-of-type:hover:before {
display: none;
}
```

I have also tried to add !important but nothing works.

Here is a link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/tgJdH

Comment: `.button:first-of-type:hover:before` [seems to work](http://jsbin.com/vapeqa/1/watch?html,css,output).

Comment: `.button:first-of-type:hover:before` works for me http://jsfiddle.net/19uuwp27/

Comment: Also are you sure `first-of type` is the selector you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/19uuwp27/2/

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working, but you guys are correct, it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution might be

```
.button:hover::before{
    content: "";
}
```

So instead of hiding the :before, simply remove it.

One more thing, it looks like when you hover the left arrow, the upper button activates, you might want to check your code.

Comment: I went with this solution, so thanks for your help. And yes you were correct, the code was screwed up, I was position it as the left button, when I was targeting the top button.

Comment: Please keep in touch, I really like that design! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the right one

```
.button:first-of-type:hover:before {
  display: none;
}
```